# Getting global scroll events with PyObjC

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

How can I get global scroll events with PyObjC? Can it be done with an NSEvent call?

Sample code would be great...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "global scroll event"? You want to find out when any arbitrary scroll view moves? (BTW, Did you ever get those Event Taps working? I hope so.)

Comment: I want to know when the user uses a two finger scroll on there touch pad. I don't care if anything is actually scrolling, I just need to know when and how much the user scrolls. I have not got my Event Tap working... (I kinda gave up for a while, until I actually need to get it working. Maybe I'll learn C before then...)

Comment: Getting a scroll event no matter what application is active? That's probably going to require an event tap too... I was monkeying around with it recently. I'll poke at it again this weekend and see if I can figure it out before you or someone else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `NSEvent`! As long as you don't want to *modify* the event, but just observe it, it's as easy as calling [`addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW16). Your app will get notified via a callback whenever an event of the type you specify [with the mask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Masks_for_event_types) is posted to another app.* The handler argument is a block, but need cause you no worry, because block arguments are almost easier to deal with in PyObjC than in straight Obj-C: you can pass any callable object (function, method, class, etc.) and the bridge will handle the rest. This is all you need to do:

```
def callback(event):
    NSLog(u"%s" % event)

NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(NSScrollWheelMask, callback)
```

In the callback, you get a copy of the actual event, that you can query for things like its [`deltaX`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-BBCEBIIF) or whatever you like.

Note, that, like so many other interesting methods in AppKit, this one is new in 10.6, and isn't in the metadata file for older (read: Apple-supplied) versions of PyObjC. This means that if you try to build an app using the default install of the bridge, it will fail. You'll have to use a newer version.

---

*If you want to get events posted to your app, you must use [`addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW17). Unfortunately, one event monitor cannot get both events for your app and for others.

Comment: Okay it seems like this should work, but when I use that code, it seems to finish as soon as it starts, and never call the callback function. Is there a PyObjC run loop I have to start or something. Forgive me if this is a stupid question...

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's not a complete script. You'll have to put this in a GUI app or start your own run loop. I seem to recall you had that part in one of your earlier questions, right?

Comment: I'm new to PyObjC, is it possible for you to elaborate on how I would start a run loop? In my earlier question I didn't entirely understand what I was doing. :)

Comment: Are you using Xcode? That's the way I always use PyObjC. If you create a Cocoa-Python App using the templates, you can stick this code in your app delegate's awakeFromNib method. I'd suggest that as the most painless method. PyObjC is about 2/3 ObjC, I'm afraid. It's tough to use without knowing the Cocoa frameworks, which means knowing a bit of Objective-C. To create a run loop by hand...I'm not sure. I'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: It work's! I tried in Xcode and everything's working, but there's just one thing I don't understand, what is the NSLog for? Is it just to see if it's working or is there a practical purpose.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Yes, the `NSLog` is just so you know something's happening. No purpose once you have a real function body.

Comment: Hi, did you eventually make it work? I had a similar question logged here and am still not sure how to do this exactly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302593/is-user-interface-required-in-order-to-do-global-event-monitoring-in-cocoa
Think I've tried the awakeFromNib(self) too, but I wasn't sure how it should be done exactly ...