# Is user interface required in order to do global event monitoring in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, events, monitor, keyboard-events, hotkeys

I have a simple snippet(not MVC) of code looking like the following

```
# include <Cocoa/cocoa.h> 

int main(argc, *argv[]) {
    [NSApplication sharedApplication]
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyUpMask handler:^(NSEvent *evt){ .... }]
    [NSApp run]
}
```

When compiled as command line binary and run, the global event monitoring works, after allowing the program from system preferences -> privacy & security; then I packed it int an .app, and ran it, the global monitor stopped working even after allowing the app from privacy & security.

I'm new to Cocoa, in order to implement a simple global monitor for a packaged app, what do I need to do else?

Answer (score 1):

> then I packed it int an .app

Did you put your CLI program in an app bundle or did you start over with a new graphical Cocoa Application?

I'd suggest you create a new GUI app using Xcode's project window and then use the following snippet as your applicationDidFinishLaunching: implementation:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Boolean isTrusted = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void*[]){ kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt }, (const void*[]){ kCFBooleanTrue }, 1, NULL, NULL));
    if(isTrusted)
    {
        [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyUpMask handler:^(NSEvent *evt){ NSLog(@"Received NSKeyUp event."); }];
    }
}
```

This will automatically bring up the System Preference pane that allows the user choose wether your application should be trusted.
[AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions) requires OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).

**Update**
There are some pitfalls regarding "Support for assistive devices" when debugging a global event monitor:

- When launching the app bundle via Xcode "Build & Run" with an attached debugger, Xcode also needs to be granted Accessibility rights in the Privacy pref pane
- The global event monitor does not receive events when a window from the Cocoa app that installed the monitor is in the foreground.

Comment: I put the CLI into the bundle. Like said the global monitor works when ran in command line but not after packed & ran as a normal APP. Is there anything significantly different between these two approaches?

Comment: Can you install the global event monitor in a graphical Cocoa app instead of embedding a CLI program? This works reliably and would also make it easier to sandbox the app later. I also updated my answer.

Comment: I actually made a GUI app in xcode and put my global listener in applicationDidFinishLoad:NSNotification: running it directly in the IDE and archiving it to an application - the global listener works in both ways. I'm aware global event monitor doesn't work when the hosting app is at the front; Per the Privacy pref pane, I ticked all checkboxes on so every app was granted access. Still what I don't understand is what brought the key difference between an bundled and unbundled app, also between using and not using delegate methods.